# RTMP Authentication with Wowza Streaming Engine

Tags: ios, authentication, rtmp, wowza, videocore

I am trying to Broadcast audio and Video using RTMP by using the Videocore code from James(Great Thanks to him) https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/ in my app. the code is working fine but is missing authentication module. 
I have tried myself to implement the Authentication module in the above code but there is no enough documentation available which i can refer.

Can anybody let me know if they have implemented the authentication in RTMP or any pointer to a related documentation will be really of great help.

Comment: can you give me some guidance on how you have implemented the authentication for the above library.